# visual basicc add,clear data pop up catch

Tags: vb.net

please help to solve my visual basic problem
i have a  homework from my teacher
he said that i have to make a visual basic form and in the inside i have to put add,delete,edit,clear data.

so that's my problem, all i have done already
my code is work out, but when i try to add data to the database, it's keep catching eror 
plase fix it for me
thank you
there is the code

```
   Private Sub btnnew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnnew.Click
    Try
        If txtno.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Nomor barang tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "information")
            txtno.Focus()
        Else
            If txtnoitem.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Nama barang tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
                txtnoitem.Focus()
            Else
                If txtdec.Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox("Nama barang tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
                    txtdec.Focus()
                Else
                    If txtqty.Text = "" Then
                        MsgBox("Jumlah barang tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
                        txtqty.Focus()
                    Else
                        If txtharga.Text = "" Then
                            MsgBox("Jumlah harga tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
                            txtharga.Focus()
                        Else
                            Query = "INSERT INTO stok Values('" & txtno.Text & "','" & txtnoitem.Text & "', '" & txtdec.Text & "', '" & cmbunit.Text & "', '" & tglmsk.Text & "', '" & txtqty.Text & "', '" & txtharga.Text & "', '" & txttotal.Text & "')"
                            daData = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, Conn)
                            dsData = New DataSet
                            daData.Fill(dsData)
                            IsiList()
                            clearsemua()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Data dengan Normor ini sudah ada, Silahkan memasukkan no yang berbeda!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Pesan")

    End Try
End Sub
```

when i run it, the msgbox inside catch keep popup. what is the problem ?

Comment: You could easily figure out what error you are getting by accessing `ex.Message` inside your Catch.

Comment: how to do it ? how to accessing ex,message?

Comment: Inside the Catch add: `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)`

Answer (score -1):

try using below code

```
   Try
        If txtno.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Nomor barang tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "information")
            txtno.Focus()
        ElseIf txtnoitem.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Nama barang tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
            txtnoitem.Focus()
        ElseIf txtdec.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Nama barang tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
            txtdec.Focus()
        ElseIf txtqty.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Jumlah barang tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
            txtqty.Focus()
        ElseIf txtharga.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Jumlah harga tidak boleh kosong!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
            txtharga.Focus()
        Else : Query = "INSERT INTO stok Values('" & txtno.Text & "','" & txtnoitem.Text & "', '" & txtdec.Text & "', '" & cmbunit.Text & "', '" & tglmsk.Text & "', '" & txtqty.Text & "', '" & txtharga.Text & "', '" & txttotal.Text & "')"
            daData = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, Conn)
            dsData = New DataSet
            daData.Fill(dsData)
            IsiList()
            clearsemua()
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Data dengan Normor ini sudah ada, Silahkan memasukkan no yang berbeda!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Pesan")

    End Try
```

Comment: That's not going to fix the exception.

Comment: i did, i already change the else to else if and justin right, not gonna fix it, i just dont understand ,isnt i am already put it there,the message ?